# In ElasticSearch, should I use multiple indexes for separate but related entities?

Tags: elasticsearch

The overhead of adding indexes is well-documented, but I have not been able to find good information on when to use multiple indexes with regards to the various document types being indexed.

**Here is a generic example to illustrate the question:**

**Say we have the following entities**

- Products (Name, ProductID, ProductCategoryID, List-of-Stores)
- Product Categories (Name, ProductCategoryID)
- Stores (Name, StoreID)

Should I dump these three different types of documents into a single index, each with the appropriate `elasticsearch type`?

I am having difficulty establishing where to the draw the line on one vs. multiple indexes.

What if we add an unrelated entity, "Webpages". Definitely a separate index?

Comment: Good question. Have a look at the [Data Design Patterns](http://vimeo.com/44716955) talk given by the elasticsearch author at Berlin Buzzwords. In the end it really depends on what you are going to do with your data: how much data do you have? Do you always want to search on all your data? How would you search?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will watch that! In my specific example, I'll have about 100,000 documents of three or four types. Now you do raise a good point, perhaps a subset of the documents need to be searched 80% of the time, whereas 20% of the time all documents need to be searched. I do notice that elasticsearch has the capability to search multiple indexes when needed. (source: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/indices-types.html )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was recently modeling a ElasticSearch backend from scratch and from my point of view, the best option is putting all related documents types in the same index.

I read that [some people had problems with too many concurrent indexes](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/More-indices-vs-more-types-tp3999423p4002051.html) (1 index per type). It's better for performance and robustness to unify related types in the same index.

Besides, if the types are in the same index you can use "[_parent](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/parent-field.html)" field to create hierarquical models that allow to you interesting features for search as "[has_child](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/has-child-query.html)" and "[has_parent](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/has-parent-filter.html)" and of course you have not to duplicate data in your model.

Answer (score 9):

A very interesting video explaining elasticsearch **"Data Design Patterns"** by Shay Banon:

http://vimeo.com/44716955

This exact question is answered at 13:40 where examining different data flows, by looking at the concepts of **Type, Filter** and **Routing**

Regards